# Recommended Table Design - APEX 21.1 / Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm building a personal Oracle APEX app to get more practice that would track our 'Family Contributions' (name we use for chores). Using the following [chart / spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17S7mG6x3NFDxd5TBj-SfeCFKlcGha5s4J7aT0dadrd0/preview), what is the best way to design these data points in the database? I'm stumped on how to best handle the `CONTRIBUTORS` data.

A family contribution can be assigned to:

1. 1 family member
2. 2 family members
3. All family members
4. Conditionally based on contribution (some are just for kids, some just for parents)

Family contributions rotate weekly. Each week a number is assigned to a family member (incrementing number by 1 and 4 becomes 1) and it maps to the contribution id in the chart. My first crack (ignoring the `CONTRIBUTOR` column for now:

```sql
FAMILY_CONTRIBUTIONS
---------------------------------------------
CONTRIBUTION_ID     NUMBER          PK
PERIODICITY         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
CONTRIBUTOR_ID      NUMBER          NOT NULL  -- ???
CONTRIBUTION_DESC   VARCHAR2(1000)  NOT NULL
MON                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
TUE                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
THU                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
FRI                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
SAT                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
SUN                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
CREATED_BY          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
DOR                 DATE            NOT NULL
UPDATED_BY          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
DLU DATE            NOT NULL

FAMILY_MEMBERS
---------------------------------------------
FAMILY_MEMBER_ID    NUMBER          PK
MEMBER_NAME         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
CONTRIBUTOR_ID      NUMBER          NOT NULL
FAMILY_ROLE         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
CREATED_BY          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
DOR                 DATE            NOT NULL
UPDATED_BY          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
DLU                 DATE            NOT NULL
```

I can handle cases `1`, `2`, `3` by using a child `ASSIGNMENT` table using rows of `FAMILY_CONTRIBUTIONS.CONTRIBUTION_ID` and `FAMILY_MEMBERS.CONTRIBUTOR_ID`, but even with that not sure how best to handle case `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From purely database stand point i would recommend you create another table that has the contributers.  So your family contributions table has the assigment, then the new table has the members assigned to a contribution. Column wise: primary id, contribution id and contributer id. When you select the contributions, you  select every member assigned to a contribution from the new table, and left join with members table based on member id. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, after taking a step back, I realize I'm over-thinking this. This what I went with. Thanks for providing some clarity.